# PHP continuing in code before previous functions finished

Tags: php

I have a full-text search code that either uses faulty logic, or else it defies the way I understand PHP to work. First, I have a rather lengthy function called *file_find* that returns an array. I have an array of files called *all_files* that I step through running *file_find* on each, like this:

```
$allftsearch_results = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i <= count($all_files); $i++) {
 $current_file = $all_files[$i];
  //Run one file
  if (file_exists($current_file)) {
   $search_result = file_find($current_file, $phpfilenames[$i], $num_ands, $keywords_core, $keywords_boolean, $phpfilenames, $ascii_limit);
  //Add file results to allftsearch_results array
  if (!empty($search_result)) {
   foreach ($search_result as $keyfilename => $invpagevalue) {
     array_push($allftsearch_results, $keyfilename);
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

If I print out $current_file as it's sent to *file_find*, it reflects the order it should: the A's, then the B's, then the C's etc. But when I print out $keyfilename after the results come back, they lag behind the files actually fed to the function. I end up with something like this:

- Current file: burnham.html
- Current file: burroughs.html
- Current file: burton.html
- Current file: busch.html
- Current file: busoni.html
- Current file: butler.html
- **Returned file:** albee
- Current file: byrd.html
- Current file: byrnes.html
- Current file: byron.html
- **Returned file:** albeville
  etc.

It's all within the same if file_exists statement, so the code shouldn't even get to the if foreach ($search_result ...) until the *file_find* has finished. But apparently it's running in the background and returning results after several other files have been sent to it and stack up. This wouldn't be a problem if I was printing all the results out at once, but I have AJAX sending batches of 100 files at a time, and it's returning results all out of order, with A's coming in after B's and results being repeated when they shouldn't.

How can I make sure it waits to proceed with the code until the *file_find* is finished?

Comment: This is not a problem with `find_file` running in the background. PHP does not and cannot accidentally run some of your functions in separate threads, and even if it did it wouldn't somehow retroactively merge the results into the initial return value of the function. Your algorithm is broken in some way, thought it's hard to tell how from the sample code. What exactly does `file_find` do? Does it by chance modify `$all_files`?

Comment: What do you do to generate the array `$all_files`, and what is the source for your `find_file()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work (as I don't know what the file_find function is doing), but perhaps you could stuff the result from the file_find function ($search_result) as an argument of another function that down the array_push.  This might prevent whatever's causing the function from firing out of order.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($all_files); $i++) {
    $current_file = $all_files[$i];
    if (file_exists($current_file)) {
        filterReturn(file_find($current_file, $phpfilenames[$i], $num_ands, $keywords_core, $keywords_boolean, $phpfilenames, $ascii_limit));
    }
}

function filterReturn($search_result){
    if (!empty($search_result)) {
        foreach ($search_result as $keyfilename => $invpagevalue) {
            array_push($allftsearch_results, $keyfilename);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little silly, because even I knew that there was no way for functions to run out of order. The problem was actually that I had two arrays of file names being passed Javascript, and only one was modified while the other was just sent repeatedly. The unmodified one was the one I was printing results from.

So when it would say "Current file: butler, Returned file: albee", albee was the value in the unmodified array corresponding to the "butler" value in the correctly modified one.